# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path$

Tags: java, android

I found some solutions but I really don't know how to start.

```
"Result": [
        {
            "id": 487749,
            "deliveryid": 71472,
            "salestransactiondetailsid": 680089,
```

Here is my code.

Interface

```
@GET("api/Ontrack/Delivery")
Call<List<Delivery>> getDeliveryDetails();
```

MainActivity

```
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Delivery>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Delivery>> call, Response<List<Delivery>> response) {
            List<Delivery> get_delivery_details = response.body();

            String[] deliveryId = new String[get_delivery_details.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i<get_delivery_details.size(); i++) {
                deliveryId [i] = get_delivery_details.get(i).getDeliveryid();
            }

            listView.setAdapter(
                    new ArrayAdapter<>(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            deliveryId
            )
            );
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Delivery>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is your pojo class ?

Comment: public class Delivery {

    private String deliveryid;    


    public String getDeliveryid() {
        return deliveryid;
    }

 public Delivery(String deliveryid) {
        this.auto_id = auto_id;
        this.deliveryid = deliveryid;

Comment: Add this to your original question

Comment: Please add the `Delivery` class to your question, as @Ravi has requested.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 2 different classes based on the response you're getting.

```
class CustomResponse{
  private List<Delivery> Result;

  // getters and setters and constructors
}

class Delivery {
  // your current default class
}
```

Your interface changes to

```
@GET("api/Ontrack/Delivery")
Call<CustomResponse> getDeliveryDetails();
```

The current one was not working because it expected a list of Delivery items as a response but instead got an object called result as the first item ie,
your response would have looked something like this :

```
{
  result:....
}
```

it expected

```
[.....]
```

Incase you do not want to create 2 classes then you'll need to modify the response such that it send back only the list without the `Result:`.

Comment: Nice. You have another recommendation. And helps me a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help, could you make the answer as correct if you got the solution you were looking for.

Comment: @niel, for your reference: [how to accept answers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+accept+an+answer+at+stack+overflow&t=lm&ia=web).